# Why the program takes wrong numbers? How do we remake the program to work correct?

Tags: excel, vba

the program wrongly takes instead of 7307 values of 37307 and insert in output file as a result we
receive 350 and 27 instead of 18570 and 9

```
Sub Insertdata()
    Dim src As Workbook
    Dim fnd As Range
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("c:\input.xlsx", True, True)
    '    Set src = Workbooks("input.xlsm")
    Set Rng = src.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b:b")

    d = 1
    
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
            lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            Do Until d = lastrow + 1
         Set fnd = Rng.Find(What:=.Cells(d, 2), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not fnd Is Nothing Then .Cells(d, 4) = fnd.Offset(, 2)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then .Cells(d, 5) = fnd.Offset(, 3)
                d = d + 1
            Loop
        End With
    End Sub
```

input and output are very large files.

Input file
[image: input file]

Output file
[image: output file]

Comment: If you want the first value, why not simply use `value = Rng.cells(d, 2)`?

Comment: The Find method uses whatever the settings of your Find dialog where after your last search. If you want it to match the whole content, you must set the appropriate properties in that Find method:
    Set fnd = Rng.Find(What:=.Cells(d, 2), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

Comment: program start to work thank you